# I want a each div to show its content on a button hover

Tags: jquery, this, fadeto

I have divs which images and Paragraphs in the, when you roll over the title i want the paragraph to show, this code worked for my other site but for some reason isnt working here

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('.post-band h2').hover(function(){
        $(".entry p",this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
          //$(".entry p",this).slideDown();
        },
    function(){
         $(".entry p",this).fadeTo("fast", 0);
        //  $(".entry p",this).slideUp();
                });
```

});

```
<div class="post-band" id="post-67">

 <h2>Dale Rodman</h2>
<div class="band-image">
<img width="300" height="250" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/dale1.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="dale" title="dale" /></div>

 <div class="entry">
   <p>Dale has been passionate about music ever since he stopped being passionate about something else, when he puts his mind to something there is not stopping this machine, playing guitar since he was little his ability to absorb different styles has help to create a style like non other.</p>
<h3>Acoustic Guitar, Vocals</h3>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's your HTML mark-up? How about a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help us to help you?

Comment: albeit, the problem might be in your HTML. Will you add that to your question pls? That way one of us can get you a jsfiddle response with a working example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".entry p",this)` in your hover function looks for the selector inside `$('.post-band h2')` (inside the `h2`). You probably need a mix of `.closest()` to go up and then `.find()` to go down.

But post your html to get a better answer.

Comment: It's what I suspected. Instead of `$(".entry p",this)` use `$(this).closest('.post-band').find('.entry p')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sDJDr/

The javascript I used is below and is also what ori meant above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.post-band h2').hover(function(){
        var $p = $(this).closest('div.post-band').find('p');
        $p.fadeTo("fast", 1);
        //$(".entry p",this).slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        var $p = $(this).closest('div.post-band').find('p');
        $p.fadeTo("fast", 0);
        //  $(".entry p",this).slideUp();
    });

});
```